# three.js post processing maskpass with multiple renderpass never works

Tags: three.js

I am working towards this:

[image: postprocessing renderPass_1, maskPass, renderPass_2, desired result]

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <style>
            body {
                background-color: #000;
                margin: 0px;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container"></div>
        <script src="../build/three.js"></script>
        <script src="js/shaders/CopyShader.js"></script>
        <script src="js/postprocessing/EffectComposer.js"></script>
        <script src="js/postprocessing/ClearPass.js"></script>
        <script src="js/postprocessing/ShaderPass.js"></script>
        <script src="js/postprocessing/MaskPass.js"></script>
        <script src="js/postprocessing/RenderPass.js"></script>
        <script src="js/Detector.js"></script>

        <script>

            if ( ! Detector.webgl ) Detector.addGetWebGLMessage();

            var composer, renderer;
            var box_mask, box_1, box_2;

            init();
            animate();

            function init() {

                var camera_mask = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );
                camera_mask.position.z = 6;
                var camera_1 = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );
                camera_1.position.z = 6;
                var camera_2 = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );
                camera_2.position.z = 6;

                var scene_mask = new THREE.Scene();
                var scene_1 = new THREE.Scene();
                var scene_2 = new THREE.Scene();

                scene_mask.background = new THREE.Color( 0x000000 );
                scene_1.background = new THREE.Color( 0xffffff );
                scene_2.background = new THREE.Color( 0x000000 );

                var box_mask_1 = new THREE.CircleGeometry( 2, 4 );
                var box_mask_2 = new THREE.CircleGeometry( 2, 4 );

                var singleGeometry_mask = new THREE.Geometry();

                var boxMesh_mask_1 = new THREE.Mesh(box_mask_1);
                boxMesh_mask_1.position.z = 1;
                var boxMesh_mask_2 = new THREE.Mesh(box_mask_2);
                boxMesh_mask_2.rotation.y = Math.PI;
                boxMesh_mask_2.position.z = -1;

                boxMesh_mask_1.updateMatrix(); // as needed
                singleGeometry_mask.merge(boxMesh_mask_1.geometry, boxMesh_mask_1.matrix);
                boxMesh_mask_2.updateMatrix(); // as needed
                singleGeometry_mask.merge(boxMesh_mask_2.geometry, boxMesh_mask_2.matrix);

                var material_mask = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xffffff});
                box_mask = new THREE.Mesh(singleGeometry_mask, material_mask);

                scene_mask.add( box_mask );

                var box_1_1 = new THREE.CircleGeometry( 2, 4 );
                var box_1_2 = new THREE.CircleGeometry( 2, 4 );

                var singleGeometry_1 = new THREE.Geometry();

                var boxMesh_1_1 = new THREE.Mesh(box_1_1);
                boxMesh_1_1.position.z = -1;
                var boxMesh_1_2 = new THREE.Mesh(box_1_2);
                boxMesh_1_2.rotation.y = Math.PI;
                boxMesh_1_2.position.z = 1;

                boxMesh_1_1.updateMatrix();
                singleGeometry_1.merge(boxMesh_1_1.geometry, boxMesh_1_1.matrix);
                boxMesh_1_2.updateMatrix();
                singleGeometry_1.merge(boxMesh_1_2.geometry, boxMesh_1_2.matrix);

                var material_1 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x000000});
                box_1 = new THREE.Mesh(singleGeometry_1, material_1);

                scene_1.add( box_1 );

                var box_2_1 = new THREE.CircleGeometry( 2, 4 );
                var box_2_2 = new THREE.CircleGeometry( 2, 4 );

                var singleGeometry_2 = new THREE.Geometry();

                var boxMesh_2_1 = new THREE.Mesh(box_2_1);
                boxMesh_2_1.position.z = -1;
                var boxMesh_2_2 = new THREE.Mesh(box_2_2);
                boxMesh_2_2.rotation.y = Math.PI;
                boxMesh_2_2.position.z = 1;

                boxMesh_2_1.updateMatrix();
                singleGeometry_2.merge(boxMesh_2_1.geometry, boxMesh_2_1.matrix);

                boxMesh_2_2.updateMatrix();
                singleGeometry_2.merge(boxMesh_2_2.geometry, boxMesh_2_2.matrix);

                var material_2 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xffffff});
                box_2 = new THREE.Mesh(singleGeometry_2, material_2);

                scene_2.add( box_2 );

                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
                renderer.setClearColor( 0xffffff );
                renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
                renderer.autoClear = false;
                document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

                var clearPass = new THREE.ClearPass();
                var clearMaskPass = new THREE.ClearMaskPass();
                var maskPass = new THREE.MaskPass( scene_mask, camera_mask );
                var renderPass_1 = new THREE.RenderPass( scene_1, camera_1 );
                var renderPass_2 = new THREE.RenderPass( scene_2, camera_2 );
                var outputPass = new THREE.ShaderPass( THREE.CopyShader );
                outputPass.renderToScreen = true;

                var parameters = {
                    minFilter: THREE.LinearFilter,
                    magFilter: THREE.LinearFilter,
                    format: THREE.RGBFormat,
                    stencilBuffer: true
                };

                var renderTarget = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight, parameters );

                composer = new THREE.EffectComposer( renderer , renderTarget );
                composer.addPass( clearPass );
                composer.addPass( renderPass_1 );
                composer.addPass( maskPass );
                composer.addPass( renderPass_2 );
                composer.addPass( clearMaskPass );
                composer.addPass( outputPass );

            }

            function animate() {

                requestAnimationFrame( animate );

                var time = performance.now() * 0.001  * 2;

                box_mask.rotation.y = time;
                box_1.rotation.y = time;
                box_2.rotation.y = time;

                renderer.clear();
                composer.render( time );

            }

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

this never works:

```
composer.addPass( clearPass );
composer.addPass( renderPass_1 );
composer.addPass( maskPass );
composer.addPass( renderPass_2 );
composer.addPass( clearMaskPass );
composer.addPass( outputPass );
```

if i switch out "renderPass_2" with a THREE.TexturePass it works, but it's not what I want.

Here is the codepen:

https://codepen.io/oxbits/pen/yEQLGK?editors=0010

Anyone able to combine two renderPasses with a mask?

Should I be using a different approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got it to work!  Though I'm not sure how...

Take a look:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PyJObz

One trick was not using a scene background in the 2nd render.  Instead I had to create a background mesh.

Code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <style>

            html, body, canvas {
    margin: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#fps {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    color: #fff;
    z-index: 50;
}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container"></div>
        <script src="../build/three.js"></script>
        <script src="js/shaders/CopyShader.js"></script>
        <script src="js/postprocessing/EffectComposer.js"></script>
        <script src="js/postprocessing/ClearPass.js"></script>
        <script src="js/postprocessing/ShaderPass.js"></script>
        <script src="js/postprocessing/MaskPass.js"></script>
        <script src="js/postprocessing/RenderPass.js"></script>
        <script src="js/Detector.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>


        <script>

            // if ( ! Detector.webgl ) Detector.addGetWebGLMessage();

            let scene       = null;
            let normal      = null;
            let outline     = null;
            let outScene    = null;
            let maskScene   = null;
            let light       = null;
            let renderer    = null;
            let composer    = null;
            let camera1     = null;
            let camera2     = null;
            let camera3     = null;
            let mesh1       = null;
            let mesh2       = null;
            let mesh3       = null;
            let bg_mesh = null;
            let renderTarget = null;

            let screenWidth  = window.innerWidth;
            let screenHeight = window.innerHeight;

            const clock = new THREE.Clock;

            let elapsedTime = 0;
            let frameCount  = 0;

            const init = function() {

                // SCENE

                scene     = new THREE.Scene;
                maskScene = new THREE.Scene;
                outScene  = new THREE.Scene;
                setModel();

                // SCENE CAMERA

                camera1 = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(40, screenWidth/screenHeight, 1, 1000);
                camera1.position.set(0, 0, 10);
                scene.add(camera1);

                camera2 = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(40, screenWidth/screenHeight, 1, 1000);
                camera2.position.set(0, 0, 10);
                outScene.add(camera2);

                camera3 = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(40, screenWidth/screenHeight, 1, 1000);
                camera3.position.set(0, 0, 10);
                maskScene.add(camera3);

                    scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0xffffff );

                // RENDERER

                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
                    width: screenWidth,
                    height: screenHeight,
                    antialias: true
                });

                renderer.setSize(screenWidth, screenHeight);
                renderer.setClearColor(0x000000);
                renderer.autoClear = false;
                renderer.gammaInput = true;
                renderer.gammaOutput = true;

                document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

                // POSTPROCESSING

                const renderTargetParameters = {
                    minFilter:      THREE.LinearFilter,
                    magFilter:      THREE.LinearFilter,
                    format:         THREE.RGBAFormat,
                    stencilBuffer:  true
                };

                renderTarget = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight, renderTargetParameters);

                composer    = new THREE.EffectComposer(renderer);
                composer.renderTarget1.stencilBuffer = true;
                composer.renderTarget2.stencilBuffer = true;

                normal      = new THREE.RenderPass(scene, camera1);
                outline     = new THREE.RenderPass(outScene, camera2);
                outline.clear = false;

                const mask        = new THREE.MaskPass(maskScene, camera3);
                mask.inverse = false;
                const clearMask   = new THREE.ClearMaskPass;
                const copyPass    = new THREE.ShaderPass(THREE.CopyShader);
                copyPass.renderToScreen = true;

                composer.addPass(normal);
                composer.addPass(mask);
                composer.addPass(outline);
                composer.addPass(clearMask);
                composer.addPass(copyPass);

                // EVENTS

                return window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);
            };

            var setModel = function() {

                    var box_mask_1 = new THREE.CircleGeometry( 2, 4 );
                    var box_mask_2 = new THREE.CircleGeometry( 2, 4 );

                    var singleGeometry_mask = new THREE.Geometry();

                    var boxMesh_mask_1 = new THREE.Mesh(box_mask_1);
                    boxMesh_mask_1.position.z = 1;
                    var boxMesh_mask_2 = new THREE.Mesh(box_mask_2);
                    boxMesh_mask_2.rotation.y = Math.PI;
                    boxMesh_mask_2.position.z = -1;

                    boxMesh_mask_1.updateMatrix(); // as needed
                    singleGeometry_mask.merge(boxMesh_mask_1.geometry, boxMesh_mask_1.matrix);
                    boxMesh_mask_2.updateMatrix(); // as needed
                    singleGeometry_mask.merge(boxMesh_mask_2.geometry, boxMesh_mask_2.matrix);


                    var box_1_1 = new THREE.CircleGeometry( 2, 4 );
                    var box_1_2 = new THREE.CircleGeometry( 2, 4 );

                    var singleGeometry_1 = new THREE.Geometry();

                    var boxMesh_1_1 = new THREE.Mesh(box_1_1);
                    boxMesh_1_1.position.z = -1;
                    var boxMesh_1_2 = new THREE.Mesh(box_1_2);
                    boxMesh_1_2.rotation.y = Math.PI;
                    boxMesh_1_2.position.z = 1;

                    boxMesh_1_1.updateMatrix();
                    singleGeometry_1.merge(boxMesh_1_1.geometry, boxMesh_1_1.matrix);
                    boxMesh_1_2.updateMatrix();
                    singleGeometry_1.merge(boxMesh_1_2.geometry, boxMesh_1_2.matrix);


                    var box_2_1 = new THREE.CircleGeometry( 2, 4 );
                    var box_2_2 = new THREE.CircleGeometry( 2, 4 );

                    var singleGeometry_2 = new THREE.Geometry();

                    var boxMesh_2_1 = new THREE.Mesh(box_2_1);
                    boxMesh_2_1.position.z = -1;
                    var boxMesh_2_2 = new THREE.Mesh(box_2_2);
                    boxMesh_2_2.rotation.y = Math.PI;
                    boxMesh_2_2.position.z = 1;

                    boxMesh_2_1.updateMatrix();
                    singleGeometry_2.merge(boxMesh_2_1.geometry, boxMesh_2_1.matrix);

                    boxMesh_2_2.updateMatrix();
                    singleGeometry_2.merge(boxMesh_2_2.geometry, boxMesh_2_2.matrix);

                    const matColor = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                    color: 0x000000});
                mesh1 = new THREE.Mesh(singleGeometry_1, matColor); // geometry, matColor);
                scene.add(mesh1);

                // flat mask
                const matFlat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                    color: 0x000000});
                mesh2 = new THREE.Mesh(singleGeometry_mask, matFlat);
                maskScene.add(mesh2);

                    const matColor2 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                    color: 0xffffff});
                mesh3 = new THREE.Mesh(singleGeometry_2, matColor2);
                outScene.add(mesh3);

                    const matColor3 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                    color: 0x000000});

                    bg_mesh = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CircleGeometry( 100, 4 ), matColor3);
                    outScene.add(bg_mesh);
                    bg_mesh.position.set(0, 0, -10);

            };

            var onWindowResize = function() {

                screenWidth  = window.innerWidth;
                screenHeight = window.innerHeight;

                camera1.aspect = screenWidth / screenHeight;
                camera2.aspect = camera1.aspect;
                camera3.aspect = camera1.aspect;

                camera1.updateProjectionMatrix();
                camera2.updateProjectionMatrix();
                camera3.updateProjectionMatrix();

                return renderer.setSize(screenWidth, screenHeight);
            };

            var animate = function() {

                updateFps();
                requestAnimationFrame(animate);
                return render();
            };

            var render = function() {

                const now = Date.now();
                const delta = clock.getDelta();

                if (mesh1) {
                    mesh1.rotation.y += 0.015;
                    mesh2.rotation.y = mesh1.rotation.y;
                    mesh3.rotation.y = mesh1.rotation.y;
                }

                return composer.render();
            };

            var updateFps = function() {

                elapsedTime += clock.getDelta();
                frameCount++;

                if (elapsedTime >= 1) {
                    $('#fps').html(frameCount);
                    frameCount  = 0;
                    return elapsedTime = 0;
                }
            };


            init();
            animate();

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just saying, the codepen doesn't work because `Detector` is not found (I think it's been moved somewhere else or renamed); if you comment that line out, it all works though.

Answer (score 0):

Just chiming in because I don't know the specifics of your situation but I have used the composer before...

What if you just add the texturePass after the maskPass and leave the renderPass1 as the next one after that?

The composer works by applying operations through a succession of buffers, so in between operations you sometimes have to do a texturePass to copy the current output back to the input for the next pass...

But this is just a guess, in case nobody else answers....

Comment: Weird.. -2 on my answer just for trying to help? Ya'll are cold blooded!!

Comment: manthrax, wasn't me, not sure why folks would do that, but once i post more, i'm sure the data will go our way

Comment: Thanx manthrax! The discussion got me thinking, so I doubled down and solved it.  Take a look!